# The observer pattern is two modules or is one module?

Tags: design-patterns, module, ooad

We can say that the Observer pattern is two modules (maybe it depends on the context) ?

think: **Subject** is another module **Observer** another module (and they're related to each other. Well, we know that from the pattern).

Answer (score 1):

Well observer pattern can be both one module or two module. It's not specific like that. But observer pattern is mostly useful when two associated classes are in different modules or subsystem. Morever, it is used to reduce interconnection between classes and let objects communicate with each other without knowing other object's classes.

[image]

You might have already studied this picture as per my guess. Here, Subject and Observer are two different classes or modules. Observer is mostly abstract class and ConcreteObserverA and ConcreteObserverB implement Observer class's method notify() to notify respective observers. Similarly, Subject class can handles methods similar to shown in the picture. Subject class generally contain information to notify to observer.

In this way, you can split modules.

Furthermore, you can study more about Observer Pattern from book "Object Oriented Software Engineering" by Timothy C.Lethbridge and Robert Lagniere.

Comment: I also think so that there is an observer pattern is the two modules can say yes (Well, regardless of the context)? The essence of the pattern The observer is on this phrase "observer pattern is mostly useful when two associated classes are in different modules or subsystem".

Comment: Well, design principles generally vary, but if you need to be specific and give concrete answer than yes it is true to say "Observer pattern is used in two modules."